# How to use f:form.select with onclick:

Tags: javascript, typo3

I want to jump to a controller action if somebody is selecting a new item from the select box, by using additionalAttributes.

```
<f:form.select name="ExtList" property="{extList}" value="extList" options="{dirs}" additionalAttributes="{onchange: 'alert(\'inline js is bad\')'}" />
```

That works fine, but I don't want to see an alert box. Instead of the alert box, I want to start in `testAction` in the controller.
How does it work? I don't have any experience with JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to a new controller, you will need to fire a redirect function in JS.

basic principle  :

```
$('#selectEl').change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

aldo you will need to add your parameters for your controller etc ..

Comment: Hi Ryan,
JS is absolute new for me. Therefore I really don't understand what I have to do with your code example.

Comment: What I have lerned, I can call a JS function via:
    additionalAttributes="{onchange: 'onChange1()'}"

 <script language="javascript">
  function onChange1()
  {
  <f:uri.action action="xlfFiles"  />;
  }
 </script>

But the F:uri.action inside JS seems not to work.
How can I exacly implement a call to the xlfFilesAction controller with additional parameters for the controller?